# Where are the Organizer and Breakpoints buttons in the workspace toolbar of XCode 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I used to use very often the Organzier and Breakpoints button in the toolbar of XCode. The first simple opens the organizer with one click the second switches off or on all breakpoints in the project. But in XCode 5 I can not find these buttons. The [help of XCode 5](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-general/AbouttheWorkspaceWindowToolbar/AbouttheWorkspaceWindowToolbar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010548-CH1-SW1) still talks about these buttons but they are neither on the screenshot in the same documents neither in XCode. Somebody knows how to bring these buttons back?

Comment: I think the breakpoints button moved to the debug bar (where the  pause / continue debugger buttons are, at the top of the bottom pane)

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely right, I did not notice it!

Comment: But why on earth is the organizer button not available?

Comment: OMG!!! Please return Organized icon back!!!! I don't want go to menu every time or remember silly hotkey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the Organizer button is removed from XCode 5. And for Breakpoints button, have a look at this image: [Have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIBvu.png)

Answer (score 5):

There are no icons that show in the toolbar for Organizer and break points:

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> to enable breakpoints, and

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> for Organizer

Comment: Thanks for the Organizer shortcut! I couldn't find it anywhere in the menus!

Comment: @divya : not agree!! There is an icon to toggle all break points at once in xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it! You can get to the documentation window from the Help Menu.
[image]